# applying limit on Floor Function

Tags: limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Applying limit on a normal function is fine but I have never applied limit on floor, how do we find the following limit
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor{\frac{0.01}{x}}\rfloor}{\log x}$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. It would be better if you post context _e.g._ the source of the problem, what you have tried, etc. (You can click on the edit button below the post to do so!) Otherwise the post will attract downvotes and closevotes.

Comment: What's the value of the numerator for $x=1,10,1000,\cdots$ ?

Comment: Recall that for any real $\alpha$ we have that $\alpha\leq \lfloor \alpha\rfloor<\alpha+1$. Does this help?

Comment: does the above limit exist? what will be the limiting value? infinity or zero

Comment: Do answer my question.

Comment: i don't know what values do you need.

Comment: cannot someone just solve it?

Comment: This is not how this site works. We are not here to do your homework. We are here to help you understand how maths works and put **your** brain to the problem. The questions you received are very informative once you answer them. Try it!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but I have different opinion with Kian. I think the limit exists and it is $0$.
First, I talk about how I solve this problem:
First make restriction that $x>0.01$ so that the numerator is $0$, a constant which has nothing to do with $x$. So the function become a constant function. So the limit is $0$.

Second I talk about the problem in Kian's answer:
He thinks that $x$ goes to infinity equals to $y$ goes to $0$ in two sides, actually I think it is not right. $y=0.01/x$ , $x$ increase from $0+$ to infinity, so $y$ decrease from infinity to $0+$. I think, we only need to consider the one side.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the limit by changing the variable as $y=\frac{0.01}{x}$ and so $x = \frac{0.01}{y}$. As $x$ goes to infinity, $y$ goes to $0^+$.

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\lfloor\frac{0.01}{x}\rfloor}{log x}=\lim_{y\to 0^+} \frac{\lfloor y \rfloor}{log \frac{0.01}{y}}$$

Now you need to calculate the limit at zero from the right.

$$\lim_{y\to 0^+} \frac{\lfloor y \rfloor}{log \frac{0.01}{y}}=\lim_{y\to 0^+} \frac{0 (absolute \, zero)}{a \, positive \, value} = 0$$

Therefore, it can be said that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\lfloor\frac{0.01}{x}\rfloor}{log x} = 0$.

Comment: thanks for your kind help, may allah bless you for this 1000 times

Comment: $x \to + \infty \implies y \to 0^+$, and not $y \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning @Alan. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @JasimAli please check the answer now!

Comment: @Kian: As you are new, let me tell you that on MathSE, if you encounter such a no-context problem, then you are not supposed to answer it **fully**; you can provide a hint, unless the post is edited to include details.

Comment: Thank you @ultralegend5385! First, i did not know that and I wonder why experienced users instead of explaining or helping, acting in a way that you are not welcome. Second, I was not able to write a comment on the question asked because it did not allow me, so I tried to give an answer which I shouldn't give a full answer. Thanks again for the comment.

Comment: @Kian: Exactly! If the problem has details, like his own attempts and source, then you will see a detailed answer. This is just for the sake of actual help. Just throwing the answers wouldn't help people unless they try and use their brain themselves.